# What's the proper way of handling business logic in Flask SQLALchemy models?

Tags: python, flask, model, flask-sqlalchemy, crud

I'm wondering what's the proper way of retrieving data from the model. Let's take the classes below for the example:

```
class A(db.Model):
   def get_attributes():
       return self.product_category.attributes
```

```
class Attribute(db.Mdel):
    attribute_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    label = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

Let's say that calling **get_attributes()** returns three objects of the Attribute class.

**In my route**, I only want to receive the list of attribute labels. What I'm currently doing is looping through the objects and retrieve the label property like this:

```
labels = [i.label for i in obj.get_attributes()]
```

Which I don't think is a proper way of doing it. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) between A and Attribute.

For example

```
class A(db.Model):
    # ...
    # table primary key, columns etc.
    # ...
    attributes = db.relationship(
        "Attribute",
        backref="as",
        lazy=True
    )

class Attribute(db.Model):
    # ...
    # table primary key, columns etc.
    # ...
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a.id'))
```

After that, you can access certain "a" attributes with a.attributes. To add an attribute to "a" just: a.attributes.append(a)

Comment: I'm using relationship, I did not include it in the code because it would have been large, that's not what the question is about. The question is about how to retrieve certain properties of objects in a correct way

Comment: I guess you should focus on the [lazy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html) parameter. You can retrieve properties as a kind of list. The way you do now. In that way that when you requesting A row you receive all attributes preloaded in a.attributes. 
Or you can choose lazy='dynamic' - after requesting A, a.attributes will store not data but only ready-to-go requests to access it. This way can be more memory efficient in some cases.
Hope it helps.